# Move elements with jquery based on data attr with appendTo

Tags: html, jquery

What I need is that, when loading the site, move the li element into the ul element based on the datta attr. I did it, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

```
<li class="classeul_name" data-nivelpai="BR04ZJCTF000">Nivel 1</li>
<li class="classeul_name" data-nivelpai="BR055XCTF003">Nivel 2</li>

<ul data-geral1="BR04ZJCTF000">
</ul>

<ul data-geral1="BR055XCTF003">
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
  $(window).on("load", function(){
    // Joga o nível 2
    liName = $('.classeul_name').data('nivelpai');
    $('li[data-nivelpai="'+liName+'"]').appendTo($('ul[data-geral1="'+liName+'"]'));
  });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to load it into the area instead of having it start in the ul and just having it display none/block on load? I feel like it would be easier to have the dom structured correctly and have the `.on("load")` just change the display style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead on window load event you need to use the dom ready event:

```
$(function () { .... });
```

Moreover you need to loop on elements (i.e. [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)) and [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) element.

The snippet:

```js
$('.classeul_name').each(function(idx, ele) {
    var newPlace = '[data-geral1="' + ele.dataset.nivelpai + '"]';
    $(newPlace).append(ele)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li class="classeul_name" data-nivelpai="BR04ZJCTF000">Nivel 1</li>
<li class="classeul_name" data-nivelpai="BR055XCTF003">Nivel 2</li>

<ul data-geral1="BR04ZJCTF000">
</ul>

<ul data-geral1="BR055XCTF003">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `li` out of `ul` isn't valid HTML. I think it is better to do this work in server side. However you need to loop through every li and append it to relevant ul.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.classeul_name').each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo($('ul[data-geral1="'+$(this).data('nivelpai')+'"]'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="classeul_name" data-nivelpai="BR04ZJCTF000">Nivel 1</li>
<li class="classeul_name" data-nivelpai="BR055XCTF003">Nivel 2</li>

<ul data-geral1="BR04ZJCTF000">
</ul>

<ul data-geral1="BR055XCTF003">
</ul>
```

Also you can use `.append()` instead

```
$(function(){
  $('ul[data-geral1]').append(function(){
    return $('li[data-nivelpai="'+$(this).data('geral1')+'"]')
  })
})
```